# GET amount of retweets for all and each tweet from Twitter on GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, twitter, cron

I have a service with 1000 users and everyone has tweeted around 1000 times each. So the total amount of tweets from my service is around 1 000 000. And this number is increasing all the time.

My question is, how can I get and check the amount of retweets for each tweet without having my service crashing all the time because of "Cron Job Exceptions" from GAE?

My problem is that I need to update the amount of retweets for all tweets every minute if possible?

My service is running on Google App Engine (Java).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what a "cron job exception" is, except that I guess you're talking about your jobs taking too long? For that, you should utilize the [Task Queue API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/) to split up your work and execute it in parallel.

There's no way your Twitter API key is going to have enough quota for updating a million tweets every minute, though, and that would put a huge load on your app, too. Instead, you'd be better off just updating the figures when someone views their tweets, and only if it's been a reasonable interval since you last updated them.